# One-To-One apply/map in R operations

Tags: r, mapreduce, lapply, sapply

I've got 3 tibbles in a `list` that I would like to add a column, for each, with a different value. I found it struggling to do this apart from using the usual `for` loop (granted, `for` may well be the best solution in this use case, but I am curious if there's a clever solution).

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

t1 <- tibble(a=1:10, b=2:11, c=3:12)
t2 <- tibble(a=1:10, b=2:11, c=3:12)
t3 <- tibble(a=1:10, b=2:11, c=3:12)
tlist <- list(t1, t2, t3)

names <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

The result I wanted to achieve would be the same as that we do `dplyr::mutate` on each `tibble` to add that extra column with values in `names` respectively; to illustrate:

```
t1 %>% mutate(name=names[1])
t2 %>% mutate(name=names[2])
t3 %>% mutate(name=names[3])
```

I've tried `lapply`, `sapply`, and `mapply` (and some combinations of either two of them), or `purrr::map`, I couldn't see a way of applying `mutate` action of a single value on a single tibble (i.e., one-to-one apply/map). `Python` has `zip` which sometimes creates a pair of values that we can easily access in `apply` functions, but we don't have that facility in `R`.

A piece of pusedo-ish code in R (which mimics what `zip` in `Python` would be like):

```
args <- pair(tlist, names)

add.col <- function(arg.pair) -> {
    arg.pair[[1]] %>% mutate(name=arg.pair[[2]])
}

res <- args %>% lapply(add.col)
```

Note that `apply` functions do not take in `Pair` object (an utility from `stats` package).

It's very likely there's blind spot for me as I became increasingly obsessed with `apply`; is there a clever way to do this one-to-one mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map2`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(tlist, names, 
     ~ .x %>% 
       mutate(name = .y))
```

Or in base R with `Map`:

```r
Map(function(x, y) transform(x, name = y), tlist, names)
```

output:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 × 4
       a     b     c name 
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     2     3 A    
 2     2     3     4 A    
 3     3     4     5 A    
 4     4     5     6 A    
 5     5     6     7 A    
 6     6     7     8 A    
 7     7     8     9 A    
 8     8     9    10 A    
 9     9    10    11 A    
10    10    11    12 A    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 × 4
       a     b     c name 
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     2     3 B    
 2     2     3     4 B    
 3     3     4     5 B    
 4     4     5     6 B    
 5     5     6     7 B    
 6     6     7     8 B    
 7     7     8     9 B    
 8     8     9    10 B    
 9     9    10    11 B    
10    10    11    12 B    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 × 4
       a     b     c name 
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     2     3 C    
 2     2     3     4 C    
 3     3     4     5 C    
 4     4     5     6 C    
 5     5     6     7 C    
 6     6     7     8 C    
 7     7     8     9 C    
 8     8     9    10 C    
 9     9    10    11 C    
10    10    11    12 C
```

Comment: I knew I'd learn something; thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

`mapply` also works:

```r
mapply(mutate, tlist, name=names, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Comment: And it does! this is a clever one; I didn't expect `mapply` to understand the mapping between `tlist` and `names`

Comment: @stucash `mapply` doesn't understand much here. It just successively takes the corresponding elements of what you feed it (`...`) and applies `FUN` to them.

Comment: there's a silent `=` in `mutate`, which was presumed by `mapply` I suppose; but yes, that `=` will always be there; good to know this little trick :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(setNames(tlist, names), ~ .x %>%
    mutate(name = .y))
```